# Using the java.ext.dirs property causing currency to display incorrectly

Tags: java, java-8, locale

I'm trying to implement my own locales through creating an extension and using the "java.ext.dirs" property, however I can't seem to figure out why the following is happening.

First without the property using the following code:

```
Locale swedishLocale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
NumberFormat swedishFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(swedishLocale);
System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(23));
```

Output:

```
23,00 kr
```

I then tried using the property "java.ext.dirs" to add my own extension and noticed that the currency output on an unrelated locale had changed to:

```
SEK 23.00
```

To test things out I tried specifying the "java.ext.dirs" property pointing to a completely empty directory, still the output had changed from the default:

```
SEK 23.00
```

Should changing the property be causing Java to behave this way (Affecting unrelated Locales), even if the property is pointing to an empty directory or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: what java version are you using ?

Comment: Java 8 Update 162

Comment: can you post the source of the extension

Comment: The extension was just an extended DateFormatProvider to be used for a custom locale not supported by Java and return some custom date formats (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html). The custom Locale actually worked fine. But what I can't understand is why having the property is causing unrelated Locales to change behaviour. As said above even having the property pointing to an empty directory changes the Locale behaviour.